# vtiger 7, query limit/offset/count not working

Tags: jquery, limit, vtiger

I'm trying to fetch some records from my vtiger but I'm encountering several issues:

1. query limit is 100 and there is no way to increase it. I tried to set the limit manually inside the query but that works only for limit less than 100; I also tried editing the include/webservices/vtql_parser.php file to try and increase the limit > 100 but it doesn't change anything, the limit is still 100
2. as a workaround, I thought about getting the total number of records and looping through several queries with an offset, thus getting all the records I need. But the query "select count(*) from $module where $condition;" returns false instead of the total number of elements
3. Even if I manually write the offset in the query the result is still false.

So basically, the only way the query works is to have a generic "select $fields from $module where $conditions;" there's no way to use limit, offset and or count whatsoever.

Is this intended behaviour? How can I get all the records when they are more than 100?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to change $list_max_entries_per_page value from config.inic.php file and try executing your query and check how many rows it returns.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the query limit with success by editing vtql_parser.php

There is 2 lines to edit :

Line 307, I replace :

```
$field = ($field>100)? 100: $field;
```

by

```
$field = ($field>100)? 100000000000: $field; // ALTAIR - Modif JPR
```

And line 318, I replace :

```
$this->query = $this->query.' LIMIT 100';
```

by

```
$this->query = $this->query.' LIMIT 100000000000';// ALTAIR - Modif JPR
```